Create middle nodes on all interrelated other nodes
I'm having some troubles on creating a relationship-based program, what I need is to create a function to aggregate related nodes together, like this, if I have those 4 nodes:

A
B
C
D

If A -> B, B -> C, C -> D, A -> C, B -> D, like this:
nodes
When A -> D, I'd like to create an intermediate Node, replacing all relationships between those nodes with a single connection from each node to this new one. Like this:
@ <- cluster
A ->@,  B -> @,  C -> @, D -> @
So whoever is connected to @, has a relationship with all of its members
This to avoid 5x5, 10x10, 25x25 relationships, which is really heavy for memory.
I've achieved this goal in several steps, first I calculate common nodes between the twos who must be connected, if those common nodes are > 5, then I cluster them in a group and delete their connections.
Also when a connection is removed, meaning that under a certain lower bound, the cluster must be dismantled and all single relationships between nodes must be recreated,
If common users are > 100 this approach could be dangerous.
I'd like to know if someone could help me to do such things, as the creation of the cluster or dismantling it in reasonable time, because now my technique is O(n) and is very resource consuming
Thank you in advance

I cannot see the correspondence between the example graph you describe  ( A,B,C,... ) and image you linked to.  Did you link to the wrong image?

What problem are you trying to solve? If a user can be connected to any number of other users, then you must have the resources to maintain all the possible relationships. Removing a user is a potentially O(n) operation and there's not much you can do about it. At some point you'll have to delete that user's connections. You can perhaps mark a user as deleted and ignore its connections, and remove the records at a later time. 100 users would be only 10,000 total connections possible: quite manageable even on a modest computer today. Things might start to get interesting with 10,000 users.

What exactly do you mean by a 'relationship' between nodes?  Best guess: if a node is reachable from another, the two nodes have a relationship.  If so, could you clarify this by editing your question.

I am thinking that what you call a 'cluster' is what is called in graph theory a 'strongly connected component in a direct graph'  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component
You ask for a better performance than O(n) but you do not say what n is.  Perhaps it is the number of nodes?  The best algorithm for finding strongly connected components is O(V+E) where V is the number of nodes and E is the number of connections.  So what you ask for is impossible.
